# Regex - Optional Positive Lookbehind

Tags: java, regex

I'm trying to match such that all the characters after the last `/` and before `.` gets matched.  My current challenge is that `.` is only sometimes present.

I have an example here: https://regex101.com/r/ThWZwX/3

Where I'm hoping to match the 'match' text in both scenarios.

Thanks,

Comment: Lookarounds are very flavor-depending. Which one are you using?

Comment: Capture it - [`^(?:.*\/)?([^.]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/2dBXgB/3)

Comment: @Yunnosch I'm using java

Comment: If it is Java you could try `(?<=/)(?![^\n/]*/)[^.\n]*`

Comment: That worked!  Thanks @revo

Comment: You don't need a lookbehind and a lookahead to make matching slow.

Comment: I was sure that he needed a direct match. No capturing group etc. @anubhava

Comment: What's more important, the _last /_ or the last / with a dot ?

Comment: @revo: OP is using Java and that will require him to use `Pattern` and `Matcher` anyway so using `.group()` or `.group(1)` won't make any difference for the added benefit of efficiency.

Comment: @anubhava I'm aware of it.

Comment: @revo: Of course you are :) that was only of OP not for you

Answer (score 2):

You can use negated character class in a capture group without any need of a lookahead:

```
.*\/([^.]*)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/ThWZwX/5)

We use `.*\/` to match last `/` by using a greedy match of `.*` and then we use negated character class `[^.]*` to match until we get a dot or everything if dot is not found.

Also note that we use `([^.]*)` to capture this match.

Answer (score 1):

No need for anything complex

`/([^/.]*)(?!.*/)`

https://regex101.com/r/KHyXcJ/1